What is the idiomatic in Rust's nom way of turning (mapping) a parsing-error into an Ok-result?
I am not sure If I'm thinking wrong about the whole thing. Maybe there is a simpler solution.
In nom I want to parse C-style single line comments. Each line that I parse could theoretically contain a "// some comment" on the right side. I wrote a parser that can Parse these comments:
pub fn parse_single_line_comments(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    recognize(pair(tag("//"), is_not("\n\r")))(i)
}

It works in the case of a comment being present. But unfortunately if there is no comment it returns an error. Now I would like it to return an empty String instead (or later I could return an option, which would be more elegant).
In my nom-learning I had this problem quite often - that I want to replace an error with a custom OK-variant. But I am never sure If I did it in the "right" way i.e. the idiomatic way of nom/rust. It always felt ugly as I was matching the return value of the parsing function. Think of it like this:
pub fn parse_single_line_comments(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    match recognize(pair(tag("//"), is_not("\n\r")))(i) {
        Ok((rest, comment)) => Ok((rest, comment)),
        _ => Ok((i, "")),
}

It looks kind of strange to me. There should be a better way to do this, right?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or

Check out nom's custom_error.rs example

You already hinted a bit at it yourself. You could use optional to parse zero-or-one line comments, or many0 to parse zero-to-many. Then combine that with preceded, and you can easily discard zero-to-many comments (and whitespace).
Let's consider a simple parse_ident to parse identifiers, that looks like this:
use nom::bytes::complete::take_while1;
use nom::{AsChar, IResult};

fn parse_ident(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_while1(|c: char| c.is_alpha() || (c == '_'))(input)
}

Now, again, let's say we want to skip zero-to-many whitespace and comments beforehand. First we can define our line comment parser (which you already did):
fn parse_single_line_comment(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    recognize(pair(tag("//"), is_not("\n\r")))(input)
}

Now we'll change parse_ident to use preceded and many0 to skip zero-to-many line comments. Additionally, we can also throw in multispace1 to skip zero-to-many whitespace as well:
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::{is_not, tag, take_while1};
use nom::character::complete::multispace1;
use nom::combinator::recognize;
use nom::multi::many0;
use nom::sequence::{pair, preceded};
use nom::{AsChar, IResult};

fn parse_ident(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    preceded(
        // Parsers to skip anything that is ignored
        many0(alt((
            parse_single_line_comment,
            multispace1,
        ))),
        // Identifier parsing
        take_while1(|c: char| c.is_alpha() || (c == '_')),
    )(input)
}

Which now allows us to successfully parse the following:
assert_eq!(
    parse_ident("identifier")
    Ok(("", "identifier"))
);
assert_eq!(
    parse_ident("     identifier"),
    Ok(("", "identifier"))
);
assert_eq!(
    parse_ident("// Comment\n  identifier"),
    Ok(("", "identifier"))
);
assert_eq!(
    parse_ident("// Comment\n// Comment\n  identifier"),
    Ok(("", "identifier"))
);

Depending on what you're parsing, then you'll need to sprinkle that preceded in various parsers. We can simplify the duplicate code a bit, by introducing our own skip_ignored parser:
fn skip_ignored<'a, F>(parser: F) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str>
where
    F: FnMut(&'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str>,
{
    preceded(
        many0(alt((
            parse_single_line_comment,
            multispace1,
        ))),
        parser,
    )
}

fn parse_ident(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    skip_ignored(
        take_while1(|c: char| c.is_alpha() || (c == '_')),
    )(input)
}

Whether there's easier ways to do this highly depends on your data. But as long as you simply want to discard the whitespace and comments, then it's relatively straight-forward.

Since you actually asked about custom errors, then you can define your own enum as you otherwise would, and then impl ParseError:
use nom::error::{ErrorKind, ParseError};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyParseError<'a> {
    IdentTooLong,
    Nom(&'a str, ErrorKind),
}

impl<'a> ParseError<&'a str> for MyParseError<'a> {
    fn from_error_kind(input: &'a str, kind: ErrorKind) -> Self {
        Self::Nom(input, kind)
    }

    fn append(_: &'a str, _: ErrorKind, other: Self) -> Self {
        other
    }
}

Using it could look like this:
use nom::bytes::complete::take_while1;
use nom::{AsChar, IResult};

fn parse_ident<'a>(input: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, MyParseError<'a>> {
    let (input, ident) = take_while1(|c: char| c.is_alpha() || (c == '_'))(input)?;

    // Return error if identifier is longer than 10 bytes
    if ident.len() > 10 {
        Err(nom::Err::Failure(MyParseError::IdentTooLong))
    } else {
        Ok((input, ident))
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_ident(""));
    // Err(Error(Nom("", TakeWhile1)))   

    println!("{:?}", parse_ident("hello"));
    // Ok(("hello", "hello"))

    println!("{:?}", parse_ident("this_is_a_very_long_name"));
    // Err(Failure(IdentTooLong)) 
}

There's also FromExternalError, which works hand-in-hand with map_res. This is useful if say you want to call str::parse() and be able to easy map it into your MyParseError.
See also:

custom_error.rs example
error_management.md


Thank you for all the explanations! I am still in the process of understanding everything.
One thing that I am puzzled a little though is the use of many0. Is this used because nom does not have a maybe-parser that can parse or ... well: not parse? I think I don't see the forest for all the trees here.
I basically need a function that is "maybe" parsing a comment at the end of a line. If there isn't a comment it shall still return an empty str. (that's why I did the strange error-replacement match).

what specifically confuses me is that the function preceded is used. I would use terminated as the single-line comments have to be to the right side of uncommented text.

Ok, I slowly understand some things. What confused me was the use of alt and many0. I always used tuple: tuple((space0, stuff_parser, maybe_comment_parser)). many0-seems imprecise as I don't expect arbitrarily many instances. I should've given more context. I want to parse a multiline-objects later. So later I will use many0 to parse instances. But at this level I only need a way parsing "specific_thing\n", or MAYBE "specific_thing // comment \n". Both shall return "specific_thing".
maybe many0 really is the only way, though. Will process further :-)

In relation to my example. We're still parsing ONE identifier. The many0 allows skipping 0-to-many whitespace and line comments. Say the input is // 1\n// 2// 3\n\n\nvariable. Then using many0 will ensure that we skip all 3 line comments + the 2 empty lines, then finally parsing the variable identifier

I think I am a little stupid sometimes. I didn't understand what I was reading: In your answer you gave me the perfect answer right at the beginning: use opt. I didn't find opt in the nom-docs because it was somehow hidden or in a place that I didn't expect it. It's basically everything I need for now. Your detailed description somehow seemed to be the most important part. But for now opt is much more fitting :-)
Now that I understand opt I can also better understand the rest you explained beneath :-)
